# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'open')]

Tags: javascript, salesforce, bubble-chart

I'm trying to export bubble chart, which giving me the error

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'open')]
```

Code for export:

```
const charts = $('#chart-container').highcharts();
charts.exportChart();
```

Libraries getting utilised for this are:

```
Highcharts JS v9.1.0,

https://code.highcharts.com/js/modules/exporting.js
```

I tried this [solution](https://jsfiddle.net/skalpana_net/o1etLkfn/3/) too, but this is failing.
The export should look like this [image]
Please help me with the suggestion to solve this issue. Thanks

Comment: A minimal reproducible example would make it much easier to help. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thanks @Raffael, but when I tried to reproduced it using JSFiddle that same code is working, while breaking in salesforce.